# Kitten is biting please help

Tags: cats, biting

I have a 9 week old kitten that is biting alot. I had my brother stay with me for a few weeks and unfortunately I think he was mistreating her. I noticed her hiss at him when he would approach her which I had never even seen her do before! He would hold her and not put her down when she clearly wanted down until I would say something. I think it is crazy that he would seriously do little things to her that she did not like even after I had told him not to. because of these kinds of things he was told to leave my home.

But now my kitten is biting a lot. I believe she still trusts and loves me. She nudges my face with hers and my lap is her favorite place. We bonded from the beginning of me having her and she clearly knows I'm her human.  But she has been biting alot when we play. She is also biting blankets, the corners of shelves etc and I'm concerned. I wonder if it could also be pain and or teething, possibly inbreeding causing aggression?

I'm trying to do a couple of things to correct the biting. I try to devote time everyday to play with her so she gets her kitten energy out. And I try to show her that I don't like it when she hurts me by stopping playing and ignoring her. But she gets so aggressive at times it cannot be ignored. I just want her to be ok and not to grow up biting people. Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: Does she only bite you when you are playing?

Comment: Well,  not just when we are playing she also does it when SHE  is playing. She's not being mean like a  animal that is attacking .  she's trying to play but it is too ruff. When walking she will go after my feet and ankles biting them. I have lifted my leg up and she will be hanging by her mouth from my pant leg!. When I put her down off the bed and tell her "no" she often will get more aggressive   I have started putting her in a cat carrier  because of it. I don't like the idea of her being in a cage . I'm not certain how affective

Comment: Cont..  it is because she often is purring while inside it. She also seems to do it when she wants something such as my attention .

Answer (score 1):

## Your kitten is teething

Your kitten is 9 weeks old, which is roughly the time when they start losing their baby teeth and start growing their adult teeth. This causes the kitten to chew on a lot of things.

There are special teething toys for kittens that are safe to bite on and won't harm their teeth (as opposed to say.. chewing on the furniture) , but this is perfectly normal cat behavior for this age, and doesn't automatically mean she'll grow up to bite people.

When the kitten bites you, gently put her away and don't continue playing. This will teach her that biting during play isn't allowed and it will stop play time. Give her something else soft to chew on instead.

A visit to your vet could tell you if perhaps the kitten's teeth are growing too closely together, which might be causing her discomfort.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense and the info is appreciated